# regular expression to replace ' single quote with blank

Tags: regex

```
insert into xpatjobs_area_city (area_id,type,name) values(143,'city','isola d'istria');
insert into xpatjobs_area_city (area_id,type,name) values(143,'city','d 'isria');
insert into xpatjobs_area_city (area_id,type,name) values(143,'city','ISO d'iuitria')
;
insert into xpatjobs_area_city (area_id,type,name) values(143,'city','ijuid'iskjitria');
insert into xpatjobs_area_city (area_id,type,name) values(143,'city','riad'istia');
```

i want to replace `'` with blank i tried to replace the text using regular expsn 
using text editor

```
([a-zA-Z])'([a-zA-Z])
```

but it selects a d'i for 'isola d'istria

i have a full paragraph to replace

Comment: Why not use just `'` as your regex?

Comment: You should tell us witch OS you run

Comment: Windows xp ..and i want to replace only ' within the word and not the one at the end

Comment: instead of removing the `'` you can escape it with another `'` in sql, see e.g. http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_escape_special_characters_when_writing_sql_queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will match the relevent `'` within the names but not the `'` surrounding the strings

```
(?<=[\w\s])'(?=\w)
```

(tested using Sublime Text 2 text editor)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.replace(/('[a-zA-Z]+)'([a-zA-Z]+')/g, '$1$2');
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick using `sed`:

```
sed -E "s/(.*[a-zA-Z ]+)'([a-zA-Z ]+.*)/\1 \2/g" file.txt
```

If you want to save the changes back to the file use the `-i` option:

```
sed -Ei "s/(.*[a-zA-Z ]+)'([a-zA-Z ]+.*)/\1 \2/g" file.txt
```

If you want to save the changes to a new file then redirect the output:

```
sed -E "s/(.*[a-zA-Z ]+)'([a-zA-Z ]+.*)/\1 \2/g" file.txt > newfile.txt
```

Sed for windows can be found [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm), or even better [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) is a collection of tools which provide a Linux look and feel environment for Windows.